# ¿Le podemos poner sombreros al usuario de la comunidad?

Tags: discusión

Viendo la versión gringa me hallé esto:
[image: comunidad con sombrero]

Casi me convierto en un puntero nulo e la emoción al ver que su comunidad también puede usar sombrero.

No sé ustedes, pero yo lo quiero para nuestra comunidad. ¡Lo necesito! ( bueno casi )

Comment: tal vez podamos levantar una especie de bug? en Meta?

Comment: sí! algo que diga: "auxilio! me desmayo!, ponle sombrero a comunidad" así se leerá más urgente ( solo digo )

Comment: probemos preguntandole a nuestro CM primero..

Answer (score 7):

Fui a mirar [su perfil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad?tab=profile) y parece que nuestro bot ya tiene sombrero puesto!

Solo tiene el de Santa Claus, el de *Robocop* y el del papel higiénico.

Los moderadores podemos cambiarle el sombrero si fuera imperioso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ay es tan navideño :')

Comment: genial.. le habia preguntado a nicolas en la terminal.. pero mejor si pueden hacerlo ustedes...

Comment: y si.. ES IMPERIOSO

Comment: @gbianchi prefieres el de robocop o el que esta?

Comment: porque tengo que elegir yo? tu eleccion me parece muy correcta :p

Comment: @gbianchi no fue eleccion mia. Creo que al igual que nosotros, alguien puso "asignar este sombrero para todos los sitios" y luego cada uno para su sitio lo modificó o no. A menos que Alvaro o Jorge lo cambiaran hahah

Comment: Ahora tiene también el del papel higiénico

Comment: @lois6b se podra ponerle el sombrero de nachos?

Comment: @JackNavaRow puedo poner cualquiera que tenga disponible. De momento solo tiene 3

Comment: me pregunto como se veria con el sombrero de kiko o el de nachos